# Using wordpress category content in other site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two site. (not real domain)

one is www.companydomain.com : normal php based web site
other is www.my-wordpressblog.com : site made by wordpress

in my wordpress blog, there is a category and its list of posts.
I want to display the category and its posts in the company's site.
here is a image to clearify my explaination.

[image]

I tried to use iframe. but iframe loaded the endire my blog in the area.
I just want to display category title and its list in my company's site.

is it possible?

and it's better when I click the post, post's content shoud be display in the 
given area.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the following code into your other web site :

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

and then you can get any info you like from the wordpress into the other web site.

For more information read WordPress documentation : http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Comment: If you are huppy with my help please rate me up ;) :D

Comment: Works as long as your custom code does not conflickt with the WP (no function collisions).